# Why do we use the passé composé when saying "there have always been x"?

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical, passé-composé, imparfait

For instance, "There have always been racists" is "Il y **a** toujours **eu** des racistes" NOT "Il y **avait** toujours des racistes".

Based on what we're taught in French textbooks/classes, *the passé composé is for one-time actions* (or things completed in the past, even if they lasted a duration), whereas the *imparfait is used for continuative actions* that don't have a clear end and may continue until now. For instance, "I've been waiting for you for 3 hours!" would be "Je t'**attendais** depuis 3 heures!" NOT "Je t'**ai attendu** depuis 3 heures!"

So why is it that when we want to say "There have always been xxx" we need to use the passé composé? I am thoroughly confused!

Comment: http://www.anglaiscours.fr/present-perfect-anglais.html

Comment: I agree with Anne Aunyme. I want to add that for the second part of your question, your translation is not exactly correct. If you say "*Je t'attendais depuis 3 heures*", it means the events is passed ! ie : "*You were in a bad mood yesterday when I came*" *"I had been waiting for you for 3 hours !*" Note that if you used **pendant** instead of **depuis**, the meaning is the same and you can use *passé composé* : "*Je t'ai attendu pendant 3h*".

Comment: To come back to the correct tense, if the person just arrived the sentence would be : "Je **t'attends** depuis 3 heures !" or "Ça fait 3 heures que **je t'attends** !"

Comment: @Teleporting Thanks for pointing out my misunderstanding of "I've been waiting for you" -that clears up a lot!

Answer (score 4):

> Il y avait des racistes.

Means there was racists, suggesting somehow there are no racists anymore today. If you add "toujours" it means there was racists whatever the time period we look at, but not today. That's not what the English sentence means.

In English you are using the present perfect, not the preterit. It should ring a bell when translating it: most of the time present perfect is best translated into passé composé.